# Unable to run usethis::use_vignette

Tags: r, rstudio, devtools, r-usethis

I am trying to make a vignette,
`usethis::use_vignette("maked")`
but I am getting this error.
`Error: Function executeCommand not found in RStudio`

Initially I thought installing the package rstudioapi will help. But unfortunately that too dint help. Tried to search online but unfortunately not able to find anything.

Comment: *The executeCommand function was introduced in RStudio 1.2.1261*. Are you using an older version?

Comment: I am using Version 1.2.1226. So probably that the reason ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is the version (at least for me). I had the same problem, upgraded Studio and now it works perfectly.